# How to call an EasyAPI from an Azure WebJobs?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-webjobs

In WAMS, Windows Azure Mobile Service, you could easily configure a Schedule Service to call on any custom API that you have.  However, how is that same scenario being implemented with Azure Web Jobs in Node ? How can I access the reference to an Azure Mobile Service Client object that I can use to call an EasyAPI Service from a Mobile Apps Module, like:

```
var client = azure.azureMobile;

azure.invokeApi("customers", {
        method: "get"
    }).done(function (results) {
                               console.log('Result:'+results.result);               
    }, function (error) {
                               console.log('Error:'+error);
    });
```

Is there any available "azure"-like object that we can use from inside the WebJob code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Custom APis](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#CustomAPI) in Mobile Apps are exposed as RESTful APis, so you can simply implement HTTP requests against your Easy APIs on Mobile Apps. You can try to following code snippet in the webjob.

```
var http = require("https")

var options = {
  host: "<mobileappname>.azurewebsites.net",
  path: "/api/easyapi",
  headers: {
    "ZUMO-API-VERSION": "2.0.0"
  }
};

req = http.request(options, (res)=>{
    console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
    console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  res.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
req.end();
```

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.